# get values from object of value object[4,4]

Tags: c#, arrays, object

(C# in VS2010)

I get an object from a method called `multiplyMatrix(m1,m2)`.
The signature of this method is: `public object multiplyMatrix(object[,] m1, object[,] m2)`

Then,

```
object toCheckOutput = multiplyMatrix(m1, m2);
```

This row works, but I have to verify the data in the "array". When I watch the variable toCheckOutput in the watch window i get as value `{object[4,4]}` and as type `object{object[,]}`.

If I try to access a value of the "array" with `toCheckOutput[0,1]`, I get the following error from the compiler:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'.

Does somebody know how to solve this? I tried it with typecasts over typecasts but this didn't work either.

Comment: Please post examples of your code and explain where things went wrong.

Comment: Rather than *describe* the code, please post a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem. Casting should work fine, but we have no idea what type the object referenced by `toCheckOutput` really is. Why does `multiplyMatrix` not return something more useful?

Comment: What are these objects and why aren't you using numeric types?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the method signature should be `public object[,] multiplyMatrix(object[,] m1, object[,] m2)`.  If you have control over this API, fix it there.

If not, just cast around the problem:

```
object[,] toCheckOutput = (object[,])multiplyMatrix(m1, m2);
```

The compiler isn't letting you index `object` because `object` has no indexer; you need to make sure the compiler knows that the object is in fact an array.